# flash.net.URLRequest call stays in pending

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've got this flash/flex application and issue with `URLRequest` call. When call is made to server I get content just fine. After that content is stored in cache and next time URLRequest uses local cache to retrieve it. **Sometimes it works, but sometimes call is never finished - stays in pending**. I'm using latest flash player and different browsers. On my computer I can replicate issue using chrome and colleague can replicate on firefox. I've looked at flash player log files and there's nothing different when call is successful and when call stays in pending ...

Also my friend couldn't replicate this issue until he upgraded flash player to latest version.

I believe this isn't a server-side issue because web server logs says there's no request at the time of the issue and network tool in google chrome confirmed that that time request is using local cache.

Currently I've resolved this by forcing client not to use cache using expiration date and no-cache, but I would like to use cache and I would like to understand why this happens.

Thanks a lot!

Responsible code:

```
loader = new utils.URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, this.onLoad);
loader.addEventListener(flash.events.IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, this.onErr);
loader.load(new flash.net.URLRequest(URL));
```

---

update:

Now I found out that cache isn't resposible for it. I've cleaned cache every time before a request and still I can reproduce this error. GET request is still displayed as pending, but this time I got wireshark running which shows interesting result - troubled GET request isn't logged in wireshark. How can this be possible?

Comment: Did u get any errors? when call is never finished?

Comment: I'm going with my gut and say that the timing is off on your result.  Please post your code.

Comment: I didn't get any errors. I believe there's no error because there's no timer set and in documentation says idleTimeout is 0 by default.

Comment: i'd suggest to use a `Timer` to drop dead requests

Comment: www0z0k, I'll pass that request to application developers. I would like to write a short explanation also. Is it normal to get dead requests? Why is it happening (I understand server-side case, but why with local cache)?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to listen to all kind of errors an URLLoader could dispatch : [URLLoader's Adobe LiveDoc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#eventSummary)

If you're not in debug mode, some errors can be thrown but not caught and, therefore, stay silent.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already listening to IOErrorEvent so there's only SecurityErrorEvent left? Should I perhaps set .load call inside try catch (error:Error) block? .swf isn't in debug mode, but I have debug version of flash player.

Comment: At the bottom of the LiveDoc page about URLLoader, there is an example where we listen for anything fired by the URLLoader. I suggest you to reproduce this example as exactly as possible, so that any fired event would be caught (sorry for my poor english)...

Answer (score 0):

In the .html wrapper code that embeds your swf, try changing allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" to allowScriptAccess="always". It appears twice.