# Videos Don't Load in Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, video, http-request

On a page with 3 videos embedded, there are times when any of them may not load. On one page load, I might get all three. On another, I might get none. Usually, it's somewhere in between.

These videos are hosted by [Longtail Video Bits on the Run](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run), and the player we are using is [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/). When successful, Chrome's *Network* tab shows that the video requests are going out, they are being redirected (via a 302/Temporary redirect), and then coming back with the actual video.

However, when unsuccessful, the HTTP status shows as `(pending)`.

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

The rest of the "Big 5" browsers handle the page perfectly. All videos load, all the time. It seems to be localized to Chrome, and I'm not sure why.

The actual page I'm worried about is behind a paywall, but here is the same code duplicated for public consumption: [demo page](http://www.mckissock.com/uspap-splash/splash.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer yet, but I am working on solving the same problem and I think yours may be related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304967/flash-net-urlrequest-call-stays-in-pending)

Looking at the post above and the fact that flowplayer also seems to be using URLLoader in their implementation (See the source code [here](http://flowplayer-core.googlecode.com/svn/flowplayer/tags/flow_3_1_1/src/actionscript/org/flowplayer/controller/ResourceLoaderImpl.as)) my suspicion is that chrome and URL Loader are the common denominator.

A bug has been filed with Chrome [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=127649)

Update: I think this is a bug with chrome that has been resolved and should be fixed in an upcoming version. I am unable to replicate the problem on the nightly build of chrome on either your test page or my own.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual answer to your specific question, however:

You're using the autobuffering feature, that can produce quite a load on the network connection. It starts downloading the clips, even if the user has not revealed the intention in playing them. And 5 clips in parallel can be quite a load, especially if they are long.

I would suggest you disable the autobuffering or leave it enabled only on the first clip.